# Identify product in invoice with unique id - Xero API

Tags: xero-api

I'm trying to import invoices from xero account using the Xero API in c#. LineItems collection in invoice object represents the invoice items which are part of invoice. I want to identify products in invoice with unique Id e.g.

Invoice1 has 2 line items say P1 and P2. Sameway, Invoice2 has 2 line items again say P1 and P2. While I iterate through the collection of invoices, I want to identify product P1 and P2 with unique Id and store them in my database. Then during the iteration loop, whenever I encounter P1/P2 item, I should know that these product has already been stored to database with unique id and no need to save these products again as it has already been stored.

I thought LineItemId and ItemCode might help but LineItemId is new Id generated every time and I noticed that Itemcode is null many times. So is there any way to assign unique product id to line items?

Thanks for help,

Answer (score 0):

LineItemId is a unique ID per line item per invoice, nothing to do with the product so that's not what you want.

If ItemCode is missing or null, this means that the product is not saved in the Xero product database and has just been added as a "once off", and in theory it will never be seen again. So there is just no way to identify a product that doesn't exist. If these items really aren't just "once off" then they should be added to the database and given an ItemCode. So the problem is the way Xero is being used.

Once it is added as an Item, you can use the Items endpoint (/api.xro/2.0/Items) to also grab the ItemID which is a GUID and should be used to store in your database with the ItemCode.